# Android List Adapter inside another adapter

Tags: android, list, android-arrayadapter

So my idea is to have a one list than have another list inside of it.  The android grouping is not the solution I'm looking for.  I don't want them grouped.

The problem im having with memory leaks and all sorts of crazyness.  Like the adapter iterating through the list multiple times.  Below is my Adapter.

```
public class LotteryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LotteryBall> {

Context context;

public LotteryAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<LotteryBall> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    LinearLayout ballpanel;
    LinearLayout jackpotpanel;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtBall;
    TextView txtJackpot;

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LotteryBall rowItem = getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mainrow, null);           
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.greenbackground);    
        holder = new ViewHolder();     
        holder.txtTitle= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.LotteryTitle);           
        holder.ballpanel = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.balllayout);
        holder.jackpotpanel = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.jackpotlayout);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.title);
    for(int i = 0;i < rowItem.balls.size();i++) 
      {
        Ball ball = rowItem.balls.get(i);
        if(ball != null){
            TextView tv = new TextView(context);  //<--problem with the context its causing the adapter to go crazy 
            tv.setText(ball.number);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellowball);
            holder.ballpanel.addView(tv);

        }
      }
    //if jackpot
    TextView tvjackpot = new TextView(context);
    tvjackpot.setText("Current Jackpot: " + rowItem.amount);
    TextView tvnextdrawing = new TextView(context);
    tvjackpot.setText("Next Drawing: " + rowItem.nextdrawing);
    TextView tvpreviousjackpot = new TextView(context);
    tvjackpot.setText("Previous Jackpot: " + rowItem.lastamount);

    View ruler = new View(context); 
    ruler.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    holder.jackpotpanel.addView(tvjackpot);
    holder.jackpotpanel.addView(ruler);
    holder.jackpotpanel.addView(tvnextdrawing);
    //holder.ballpanel.addView(ruler);
    holder.jackpotpanel.addView(tvpreviousjackpot);
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rewrite**

It looks like you are creating new TextView balls regardless of the existing ones. You should see how many currently exist then add or remove the difference:

```
// Loop through the existing balls to update their text

if(holder.ballpanel.getChildCount() > rowItem.balls.size()) {
    // Remove extra balls
}
else if(holder.ballpanel.getChildCount() < rowItem.balls.size()) {
    // Add new balls
}
```

Comment: Ha, I changed my answer to reflect the "real" question. :)

Comment: So i need to check if they exist?  Why does it keep iterating through the list?  over and over

Comment: I just noticed that you add on a new "jackpot" layout each time you scroll... You need to create the "jackpot" layout inside `if(convertView == null)` and add it to your ViewHolder. But I don't know what you mean by "Why does it keep iterating through the list? over and over".

Comment: I mean when i scroll down the list on the phone (in debug) it rebuilds the list over and over.  How can i make it only build the list once?

Comment: haha, as i wrote that previous comment. put all the code in the if(convertView == null) and it fixed all my problems.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help! You should watch Android's Romain Guy [explain this phenomena](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html), if you don't already know about the view recycler. Good Luck!